# Registering Spring Cloud Microservice with Eureka server

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am trying to create spring cloud microservices and also need to include eureka server and zuul as spring cloud tools. Now I created one module in my one spring boot project. I registered that service with eureka server. And also I created one spring boot project for adding zuul service discovery and also registered with eureka project.

- Here my doubt is that When I am adding another module as another spring boot project, Can I register that application also with my current eureka server as client? What type of relation that eureka server project and microservice having? one-To-One or One-To-Many? Can I register 3 or 4 microservices with one eureka server as client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eureka Server will let you add as many microservices (modules of spring boot projects like you said).

From Spring Cloud [landing page](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/):

> As long as Spring Cloud Netflix and Eureka Core are on the classpath
>   any Spring Boot application with @EnableEurekaClient will try to
>   contact a Eureka server on http://localhost:8761 (the default value of
>   eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone):

That means that you can use a single eureka server for multiple microservices which are registered as clients to the eureka server.

So yes, it's a One-To-Many relationship.

You will want at one point to look into multiple Eureka servers used in load balancing, for redundancy purposes, but for now you will be fine.

Comment: Ok. I understood the concept. Thank you for your response.